# Converting valuestring or valueint from cJSON to send using uart_write_bytes is failing

Tags: pointers, uart, esp32

So, currently, I am sending a JSON message containing a value I need to send from an ESP32 UART uart_write_bytes, but am not sure where I am going wrong in the conversion. 
Currently, if I send 234, it goes out the UART as 50, 51, 52, and not 234.
Thoughts?
I am using esp-idf with GCC Compiler  not Arduino.

```
char hex[8] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
cJSON* message'
int intValue = 0;
char *stringValue= "999";

if ((message = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root->child, "msg")) != NULL)
{
    if((intValue = cJSON_GetObjectItem(message, "Number")->valueint) != NULL)
    {
        ESP_LOGI(LOG_TAG, " this is the Number %i ", intValue);
    }
    if((stringValue = cJSON_GetObjectItem(message, "Number")->valuestring) != NULL)
    {
       ESP_LOGI(LOG_TAG, " This is NumberString %s ", stringValue);
    }   
}

char numStrStr[3];
sprintf(numStrStr, "%s", stringValue );
for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(str); j++)
{
    hex[j] = numStrStr[j];
}

int checkIt = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_2, (const char *)hex, strlen(hex));
```

Comment: Please specify buffer name hex definition. Also specify the contents of numStrStr buffer.

Comment: I edited to include missing details.  It was late, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with the following changes:
I forgot to mention that I want to send one character at a time, so that means sending in '234' as a char, then converting it to an int, then doing the fun math of breaking it into 1's, 10's, and 100's for sending to serial.

```
cJSON *message;
int intValue = 0;
const char *buffValue = "999";

hex[0] = 0xfe;
hex[1] = 0x01;
hex[2] = 0x01;
hex[3] = 0x00;

if((buffValue = cJSON_GetObjectItem(message, "NUmber")->valuestring) != NULL)
{
   ESP_LOGI(LOG_TAG, " This is Value String %s ", buffValue);
   ESP_LOGI(LOG_TAG, "strtol %ld ", strtol(buffValue, NULL, 10));
   intValue = strtol(buffValue, NULL, 10);

    int valueArray[3] = {0};
    int increment = 0;
    while(intValue > 0)
    {
        int digitValue = intValue % 10;
        valueArray[increment] = digitValue;
        intValue /= 10;
        increment ++;
    }
    hex[3] = valueArray[2];
    hex[4] = valueArray[1];
    hex[5] = valueArray[0];
}   


int checkIt = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_2, (const char *)hex, strlen(hex));
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because ASCII code for character 2 ('2') is 50, for character 3 ('3') is 51 and character 4 ('4') is 52.

> int checkIt = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_2, (const char *)hex,
>   strlen(hex));

If you observe the above line you have explicitly type-casted hex to const char* essentially encoding the data in ASCII (assuming gcc compiler) which is the transmitted over UART.

In UART receiving device or program you need to treat the incoming data as ASCII encoded data. You could use terminal program like CoolTerm to view booth ASCII encoded and/or RAW data.

To send raw data you can avoid explicit type casting using const char * assuming data stored in hex is [0x02, 0x03, 0x04] and not ['2', '3', '4']